# Function not assigning anything to array (using pointer arithmetic)

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

My program is supposed to read in two strings and combine them in a manner that the new string(3rd) prints as 1st character in first string, then 1st of second string, then 2nd of first string, and so on. Any extra characters from the longer string are simply placed at the end.

Here the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define N 1000

void merge(char *s3, char *s1, char *s2);
int read_line(char *str, int n);

int main(void)
{
    char a[N], b[N], c[N];
    int num_chara, num_charb, num_charc, i;


    printf("Enter the first set of characters: ");
    num_chara = read_line(a, N);
    printf("Enter the second set of characters: ");
    num_charb = read_line(b, N);

    num_charc = num_chara + num_charb;

    merge(c, a, b);
    printf("Output: ");
    for (i = 0; i < num_charc; i++)
        printf("%c", c[i]);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}

void merge(char *s3, char *s1, char *s2)
{
    size_t low_limit, up_limit;
    int i;

    if (strlen(s1) < strlen(s2))
    {
        low_limit = strlen(s1);
        up_limit = strlen(s2);
    }
    else
    {
        low_limit = strlen(s2);
        up_limit = strlen(s1);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < low_limit; i++)
    {
        s3 = s1 + i;
        s3++;
        s3 = s2 + i;
        s3++;
    }

    if (strlen(s1) < strlen(s2))
    {
        for (i += 1;i < up_limit; i++ )
        {
            s3 = s2 + i;
            s3++;
        }
        *s3 = '\0';
    }
    else
    {
        for (i += 1;i < up_limit; i++ )
        {
            s3 = s1 + i;
            s3++;
        }
        *s3 = '\0';
    }
}
```

My problem is that when calling this in `main()`, printing the third string results in nothing being printed, as if the third string were empty !

The method for printing is correct, as I was able to print the 1st and 2nd string just fine. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here, as the logic of each step makes sense to me. Though I am new to C, and pointer arithmetic is still pretty vexing to me.

**Edit:**

1) I am surprised that compiling this gives me no errors or warnings (gcc).

2) Replacing the assignments of s3 with *s3 as well as *(s1 or s2 + i) made this program work for the most part. Though I am getting unexpected results with the last few characters in the output now. Thanks Christophe, but I'm trying to avoid using any array indexes in this program.

Comment: It would be helpful if you had more code/the whole program, but because you don't, can you verify that `s3` is large enough to hold all of the data?

Comment: Is `s3` supposed to be a seperate memory buffer? Please provide a [mcve] (you are almost there, just need to show `main` and how the function is called). AFAICS you never write anything to `s3` except a NUL character: `*s3 = '\0';`. And even that is probably wrong as `s3` points into either `s1` or `s2` so is trying to overwrite those.

Comment: `s3 = s1 + i;` is completely wrong. Should probably be `*s3 = *(s1 + i);`. This error occurs multiple times.

Comment: Take out both occurrences of `i += 1`

Comment: Please to not correct the errors directly in the code of your question, because otherwise, your question would no longer be consistent for any interested reader who want to understand what was the problem and how it was solved.  I re-edited your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Ouch!  In `merge()`, you're doing pointer arithmetic instead of assignment of pointed value.  This is perfectly legal, so the compiler won't complain:

For example:

```
    ...
    s3 = s1 + i;    // simply changes the pointer, not the zone pointed to 
    s3++;           // now the pointer 3 points to the address of a[i+1]
    ...             // the content of the string pointed by s3 is left unchanged
```

To solve this, you must dereference the pointer either with `*` or with `[]`:

```
    ...
    *s3 = s1[i];    // works on the character pointed to and not the pointer itself
    s3++;
    *s3 = s2[i];    // you could combine the two lines with *s3++ = s2[i]
    s3++;
    ...
```

**Important notice:** Your function `merge()` is highly unsafe: this function knows nothing about the size of the arrays. If `a` and `b` would be full with `N-1` chars and an ending `'\0'`: the function would write `2*N-1` characters to `c`, so you'll have a buffer overflow corrupting your memory.  Two easy fix for a fatal vulnerability:

- change the size of `c` to `2*N`
- change the function signature to `void merge_s (char *s3, char *s1, char *s2, size_t n)` where n would be the size of the `s3` array.

**Edit:**

Additional issue:  If one string is larger than the other, you'll skip the first char that exceeds the common length.  That's because you start the additional for-loops with  `for (i+=1;...)`  but `i` already pointed at the right char to copy.  Just change these two loops to `for (;...)`

As you justly remarked if you prefer pointer arithmetic, `s1[i]` is the same than `*(s1+i)`.  By the way, as strange as it might sound, it's also the same than `i[s1]` !

Strange chars beyond the end of the string might be caused by uncorrect length causing to output the null terminator and beyond.  Check `read_line()` to be sure that it returns the length of the string not counting the null terminator.  But that should be easy to fix with your debugger.